# "databricks repos update" returns "try logging out of ADD and logging back in"

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks, databricks-cli, databricks-repos

I am using the new Databricks cli (v0.203.2)

With a Databricks PAT, and the workspace URL, I can successfully run commands like:
`databricks repos list` and I see a list of repos

However, when I run:
`databricks repos update`, the following is returned:
*"Error: Encountered an error with your Azure Active Directory credentials. Please try logging out of Azure Active Directory (https://portal.azure.com) and logging back in."*

It is the same error that is mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/repos/errors-troubleshooting#azure-active-directory-credentials-error).

Logging in and out Azure Portal doesn't help. Why would it help?

Comment: I switched to a different Databricks PAT and now it works (??)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's more related to the authentication from Databricks to the repository in Azure DevOps (ADO) - it looks like that you configured transparent AAD authentication, but it works only in UI. If you need to work with Repos programmatically, then you need to configure [Git credentials with ADO personal access token (PAT)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/repos/get-access-tokens-from-git-provider#devops).

P.S. `databricks repos list` works because it fetches information from Databricks workspace, not from remote repo.